# Highcharts: how to update shapeOptions for arrow-segment annotation?

Tags: highcharts

I have the full code placed here: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/kr7ojvLw/36/ where you can draw a circle shape and an arrow shape. After drawing, you can select the shape and a popup (with custom UI) will appear. From there, you can choose the "fill color", "line (stroke) color" and "line (stroke) width" and after clicking "save" the settings will be applied over the selected shape.

If you try the above over the circle shape, it will work. So the actual update is handled with the code:

```
function () {
    var fillColor = document.querySelectorAll(
        '.highcharts-popup-annotations input[name="fill-color"]'
    )[0].value;
    var lineColor = document.querySelectorAll(
        '.highcharts-popup-annotations input[name="line-color"]'
    )[0].value;
    var lineWidth = document.querySelectorAll(
        '.highcharts-popup-annotations input[name="line-width"]'
    )[0].value;
    // Update the circle
    thischart.currentAnnotation.update({
        shapes: [{
            fill: fillColor,
            stroke: lineColor,
            strokeWidth: lineWidth
        }]
    });
    // Close the popup
        thischart.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

The issue here is: everything is the same, but when it comes to the arrow segment, the applied colors and widths are not applied and the arrow segment is always keeping the initial colors / widths which are pre-defined in the `navigation -> annotationsOptions -> shapeOptions`

When selecting the arrow segment and changing values in the popup, we need the arrow segment to be updated on the same way as this is working for the circle shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the shapes array directly is a solution to your issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tfzvhjcq/

```
  // Update the annotation
  thischart.currentAnnotation.shapes[0].update({
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: lineColor,
    strokeWidth: lineWidth
  });
```

Comment: and how can we preserve the selected values, so that once selected, to update the general settings at `navigation -> annotationsOptions -> shapeOptions` and all future drawn circles and segments to keep the color as the default color?

Comment: @delux As I understood you would like to achieve something like is done in the attached demo? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zosbh4uL/

Comment: yes I need that. The only remining issue is that "fill color" for "arrow segment" is still not preserved in the example you provided.

Comment: `The only remining issue is that "fill color" for "arrow segment" is still not preserved in the example you provided. ` What do you have in mind? Could you provide the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: same demo you provided https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zosbh4uL/ try this: draw a "line" (which is actually an arrow), select it, change the fill color using the custom popup, apply the changes on save (see how marker of the arrow has the new fill color). Then draw a new arrow and see how marker has the stroke color preserved and not the fill color. Select the second line and just apply the values from the popup and see how fill color is now applied. Meaning that: fill color for arrows is not preserved with the update method which you helped me with. It works for shapes.

Comment: actually never mind, I added a check and if we are having "arrow-segment" then I omit the fill color and I only use the stroke color in the popup. Thank you for your help here!

Comment: @delux I had in plans to take a look at it today, but I am glad that you figured out a satisfied solution.